# npm install -g firebase-tools not working

Tags: flutter, firebase-tools

Just created a new flutter project, and the first thing I did was use the command

> npm install -g firebase-tools

Im getting the follow error messages:

> npm ERR! code EACCES
> npm ERR! syscall mkdir
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
> npm ERR! errno -13
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
> npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'] {
> npm ERR!   errno: -13,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
> npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
> npm ERR! }
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/mateusoliveira/.npm/_logs/2023-02-15T15_06_28_910Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Everything is well explained in the error message you pasted. Have you read it, and tried anything related?

Comment: Yeah, I've read it. But I don't how to give the permissions

Comment: I just have one user, which is the administrator

Comment: @Bigood .......